# write a version number when deliver in RTC

Tags: versioning, rtc

I want to have an API, in my server, that return the version of the code running on it.
To do so, I want to have the version number on a file, and I want it to be updated each time I deliver code into the stream in RTC.

Is there a plugin I can use, or some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

RTC has no version number. A component is made by a succession of change-sets which can contains more than one file. A single file history is given by the change-sets that begin with file creation and continue to last modification. But as RTC provides streams to organize logic environment you can have streams with different history for the same file. In this context "version" has no sense. In order to work with RTC you have to think with change-set and not by single file changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with signing the manifest.mf file in every build using mvn and jenkins.

I wrote a short [artical](http://amaziagur.blogspot.co.at/) about my solution, hope someone will find it useful.